# What does this Pdesurf error message mean?

Tags: matlab, mesh, pde

I run

```
pdesurf(mesh.p, mesh.t, u)
```

I got

```
Error using pdesurf (line 25)
Illegal solution format.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose **u**

```
pdesurf(mesh.p, mesh.t, u')
```

Answer (score 1):

`PDESURF` expects input of the form `pdesurf(p,t,u)`. `u` must either be a column vector and the same length as `p`, or a row vector and the same length as `t`. I don't know how big your `mesh.p` and `mesh.t` variables are, so I can't say for sure, but it could be because you need to transpose your vector. It is possible that the error might be corrected by changing your code to

```
pdesurf(mesh.p, mesh.t, ufun(0:0.01:1,0:0.01:1)') % Note the transpose
```

If this doesn't work, then you need to make sure that either

```
size(t,2)==size(u,2)
```

or

```
size(p,2)==size(u,1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I explained now more my problem. So your second condition holds in my case.